# Laravel - relationship

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to figure out how I can get a nested relationship but without any success.

**Modal: Workout**

```
public static function getWorkout($workout_id = null)
{
  if ($workout_id) {
     return Workout::whereId($workout_id)->with('exercises.sets')->first();
  }

  return [];
}

public function exercises()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Exercise');
)
```

**Modal: Exercise**

```
public function sets()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Set');
}
```

This solution gives me all sets based on "exercise_id". I need to get only the sets within the workout.

If I do this it works, the problem is now how I should get the ID of the workout to pass. I've tried to put the relation in the Workout Model as well but then the response of sets will get outside the exercise array.

```
public function sets()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Set')->where('workout_id', 5);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following snippet where I specify a condition for the eager load.

```
public static function getWorkout($workout_id = null)
{
  if ($workout_id) {
    return Workout::whereId($workout_id)->with(['exercises.sets' => function($query) use($workout_id)
    {
        $query->where('workout_id', $workout_id);

    }])->first();
  }

  return [];
}
```

Comment: It works! Can I use $workout_id instead of 5 straight away?